# Changing scale bar units to feet in PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, scale-bar

I'm trying to change the default QGIS scale bar from meters to feet. From the [API documentation](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsComposerScaleBar.html#af7e398bcc896442b893eb6eb6f4fc644) it looks like I should be able to use the QgsComposerScaleBar.applyDefaultSize() function.

I thought this would work

```
scalebar = QgsComposerScaleBar(c)
scalebar.setComposerMap(composerMap)
feet = QgsComposerScaleBar.ScaleBarUnits.Feet
scalebar.applyDefaultSize(feet)
c.addItem(scalebar)
```

but I get the error

```
Object::disconnect: No such signal QObject::extentChanged()
```

Any ideas on how to do this, or what this error means?

I'm using QGIS 2.6.1-Brighton and the CRS for my dataset is EPSG:26917 - NAD83 / UTM zone 17N.

Comment: Have you tried: `scalebar.applyDefaultSize(QgsComposerScaleBar.Feet)` or`scalebar.setUnits(QgsComposerScaleBar.Feet)`?

Answer (score 2):

If I got you right, you can define the units of the QGIS scale bar this way:

- Using the GUI:

  Go to `Settings->Options->Map Tools->Measure Tool` and set `Preferred measurement units` to `Feet`.
- Programmatically: Open a QGIS console and copy this:

  ```
  from PyQt4.QtCore import QSettings    
  QSettings().setValue("Qgis/measure/displayunits","feet")
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help @gcarrillo!

As far as I can tell `QSettings().setValue("Qgis/measure/displayunits","feet")` had no effect, but `scalebar.applyDefaultSize(QgsComposerScaleBar.Feet)` did the trick.

For prosperity, here's a working example of changing the scale bar to miles.

```
scalebar = QgsComposerScaleBar(c)
scalebar.setComposerMap(composerMap)
scalebar.applyDefaultSize(QgsComposerScaleBar.Feet)
scalebar.setUnitLabeling("mile")
scalebar.setNumMapUnitsPerScaleBarUnit(5280.0)
scalebar.setNumSegmentsLeft(0)
scalebar.setNumSegments(4)
scalebar.setNumUnitsPerSegment(0.25*5280.0)
c.addItem(scalebar)
```